# Search text for multiple lines matching string 1 which are not separated by string 2

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I've got a file looking like this:

```
abc|100|test|line|with|multiple|information|||in|different||fields
abc|100|another|test|line|with|multiple|information|in||different|fields|
abc|110|different|looking|line|with|some|supplementary|information
abc|100|test|line|with|multiple|information|||in|different||fields
abc|110|different|looking|line|with|some|other|supplementary|information
abc|110|different|looking|line|with|additional||information
abc|100|another|test|line|with|multiple|information|in||different|fields|
abc|110|different|looking|line|with|supplementary|information
```

I'm looking for a regexp to use with sed / awk / (e)grep (it actually doesn't matter to me which of these as all would be fine) to find the following in the above mentioned text:

```
abc|100|test|line|with|multiple|information|||in|different||fields
abc|110|different|looking|line|with|some|other|supplementary|information
abc|110|different|looking|line|with|additional||information
```

I want to get back a |100| line if it is followed by at least two |110| lines before another |100| line appears. The result should contain the initial |100| line together with all |110| lines that follow but not the following |100| line.

```
sed -ne '/|100|/,/|110|/p'
```

provides me a list of all |100| lines which are followed by at least one |110| line. But it doesn't check, if the |110| line has been repeated more than once. I get back results I don't look for.

```
sed -ne '/|100|/,/|100|/p'
```

returns a list of all |100| lines and the content between the next |100| line including the next |100| line.

Trying to find lines between search patterns always was a nightmare to me. I spent hours of try and error on similar problems which finally worked. But I never really understood why. I hope, s.o. might be so kind to save me of the headache this time and maybe explain how the pattern does the work. I'm quite sure, I'll face this kind of problem again and then I finally could help myself.

Thank you for any help on this one!

Regards

Manuel

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. If you have attempted to write something and have some difficulties, then show what you have done and ask a specific question.
Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips. If you just want free work done then StackOverflow isn't the place for such requests.
At least make an attempt using the plentiful documentation that the Internet provides. That, or pay someone to write it for you.

Comment: Thought a presentation of my very basic knowledge on this, wouldn't do any good. Edited the question.

Comment: Thanks for adding your attempt. At least it's something. :) Close vote retracted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do this in awk.

```
awk -F'|' '$2==100&&c>2{print b} $2==100{c=1;b=$0;next} $2==110&&c{c++;b=b RS $0;next} {c=0}' file
```

Broken out for easier reading:

```
awk -F'|' '

  # If we're starting a new section and conditions have been met, print buffer
  $2==100 && c>2 {print b}

  # Start a section with a new count and a new buffer...
  $2==100 {c=1;b=$0;next}

  # Add to buffer
  $2==110 && c {c++;b=b RS $0}

  # Finally, zero everything if we encounter lines that don't fit the pattern
  {c=0;b=""}

' file
```

Rather than using a regex, this steps through the file using the field delimiters you've specified. Upon seeing the "start" condition, it begins keeping a buffer. As subsequent lines match your "continue" condition, the buffer grows. Once we see the start of a new section, we print the buffer if the the counter is big enough.

Works for me on your sample data.

Comment: Happy to help!  One proviso which I thought of is that if your pattern-of-lines (a 100 followed by 2 or more 110's) exists at the END of the file, it will not be printed, because printing only happens when the script sees `$2==100`. You can fix this with an `END` section that contains an `if()`, if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

In AWK, the field separator is set to a pipe character and the second field is compared to 100 and 110 per line.  $0 represents a line from the input file.

```
BEGIN { FS = "|" }
{
    if($2 == 100) { 
        one_hundred = 1; 
        one_hundred_one = 0;
        var0 = $0
    } 

    if($2 == 110) { 
        one_hundred_one += 1; 
        if(one_hundred_one == 1 && one_hundred = 1) var1 = $0; 
        if(one_hundred_one == 2 && one_hundred = 1) var2 = $0;
    } 

    if(one_hundred == 1 && one_hundred_one == 2) {
        print var0
        print var1
        print var2
    }  
}
```

awk -f foo.awk input.txt

```
abc|100|test|line|with|multiple|information|||in|different||fields
abc|110|different|looking|line|with|some|other|supplementary|information
abc|110|different|looking|line|with|additional||information
```

Comment: You want `$2 == 100` to avoid matching values like "41004"

Comment: @glennjackman yea I wasn't exactly sure from the question if he wanted a regex to match against or a literal value, updated my response as you suggested and I guess he will have to ultimately decide what he wants there.

Comment: The value searched for is exactly 100 - the information in the field is limited to numeric values between 100 and 900.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a GNU awk specific answer: use `|100|` as the record separator, `|110|` as the field separator, and look for records with at least 3 fields.

```
gawk '
    BEGIN {
        # a newline, the first pipe-delimited column, then the "100" value
        RS="(\n[^|]+[|]100[|])"
        FS="[|]110[|]"
    } 
    NF >= 3 {print RT $0}        # RT is the actual text matching the RS pattern
' file
```

Comment: I've checked, and this solution works as well. Thank you for your help!